# Using "Page Public Content Access" for Competitive Benchmarking

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy-policy

I'm looking into using the Facebook Graph API to look through posts from public pages to help clients with competitive benchmarking. After going through the docs on App Review and Page Public Content Access, I'm wondering how likely I could get approval for this.

Under common uses, Facebook categorizes the following as "acceptable":

- Provide aggregated, anonymized public content for competitive benchmarking, understanding what content resonates with people and identifying best practices

and the following as "unacceptable":

- Businesses cannot transfer or sell customer insights or competitive intelligence data to third-parties apart from the Page owner

What exactly is the line between the two?

Comment: what line? those are 2 different things. it would be much easier to answer if you would tell us what you want to do in detail.

Comment: @luschn thanks for the comment. Is it ok to look through the public content on pages of a *client's competitor,* and aggregate this information for the client? Or would this be considered as transferring customer insights to a third-parties apart from the Page owner?

Comment: i got a tool doing that exactly, and it got approved. clients can see some stats of competitor pages, with page public content access.

Comment: i got a tool doing that exactly, and it got approved. clients can see some stats of competitor pages, with page public content access.

Comment: @luschn That's cool! Hopefully I could also get mine approved as well. Thanks for your help